# JqGrid data array indexes

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I'm trying to load data array as `JQGrid` data, but indexes in array starts from about `40000` and actually are ids of elements.

Example array structure:

```
 array[45698] = array('id' => 45698, 'data', ..);
```

Is it possible to set `JQGrid` to see these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't super clear but I will take a stab here.

I think you are saying that you have an array of 45698 objects and you only want to see 5698 of those objects? If that is correct then you can filter the data into jqGrid like this:

Create a function that does something like this:

```
filtered = $.grep(array, function(value) {
              var iId = parseInt(value.id)
              return iId > 40000;
           });
```

Then run the filter on your data before you set the data to jqGrid:

```
var filteredData = runFilter();
theGrid.jqGrid({
 data: filteredData,....
```

See  [WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/9gzn2mgp/)

Lastly, I suggest using free-jqgrid, the example above is written using that fork. However if you insist on using the original jqgrid then please [see here for example](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/j33akcqs/1/) on how to do it with jqgrid v4.6